# How to create a custom(self designed) uialertview in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, custom-controls, uiwindow

I stumbled across a lovely ui concept. I am wondering how could we create a "pop up" window like this in iOS(iPhone).

[image: Concept UI]

I have 3 questions:

1. How do we achieve that pop up style window?
2. What is the best approach to do that?

Thank you

EDIT: I would like to create a custom control like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the better way is to:

1- Create a class that  inherits `UIView` and has a `delegate` class too.
your .h file should be something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MYPopUpView;

//Your delegate class
@protocol PopUpViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) popUpView:(MYPopUpView *)popUpView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index;

@end

//Your view interface
@interface LIPopUpView : UIView{
    NSObject<LIPopUpViewDelegate> *_delegate;
}
//Your methods and properties
@end
```

2- In the initializer of your .m file implement the UI of your PopUpView

3- For the circle you can use UILayer or even a custom button and when user clicks it fire your `delegate` methods.

4- Define a show methods with following code for showing the popUp:

```
- (void) show
{
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;
    [window addSubview:self];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
```

5- Fire the show method of you popUp object to show the popUp

6- For hiding it, define the close methods like below and fire it from the caller class.

```
- (void) close
{
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Sounds great, what about blurring the underneath viewcontroller though? Any idea?

Comment: Your uiview should be two view. First view is the full screen uivew with a little transparency color (for example 40% transparency) and the pop up and uilayer(or uibutton) will added to this transparent view. This transparent view will add to the window

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me the following will do:

1. Create a view controller whose view has sub-views look like the register window in the screenshot. For the non-rectangle shape, mask of the view layer may needs to be properly set.
2. Add the view of the view controller to the key window.